# Does the object variable create an instance of the object while using a for-each loop in Java?

Tags: java

I am using the following code to add a new `StockRecord` to my `stockRecords` collection. StockRecord extends Stock.

```
for (Stock s : stock) {
     stockRecords.add(new StockRecord(s.get_storeID(),
     s.get_sku(), s.get_itemCount()));
}
```

I have a println statement in the constructors of both `Stock` and `StockRecord`. When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
Stock()
StockRecord()
Stock()
StockRecord()
Stock()
StockRecord()
Stock()
StockRecord()
```

Does using the variable `s` in the for-each loop actually create an instance of `Stock`?

Comment: Does `StockRecord` extend `Stock`? If so, instantiating a new `StockRecord` will first call the parent `Stock` constructor.

Comment: @PaulBellora. You should put that as an answer.

Comment: @RohitJain Yeah, but I tend to dislike "psychic" answers - hopefully the OP updates the question.

Comment: @user1494530 Thanks - posted my answer!

Answer (score 3):

It does not.  For loops use java iterators. In each iteration of the loop, `Iterator.hasNext` and `Iterator.next` are called on the object returned by `stock.iterator()`. The `java.util` collections will not create new objects, but if you have a custom collection it might.

The other possibility is that you are creating objects in your calls to the getters or in the body of the `StockRecord` constructor itself.  Look for "new" in those places.

Comment: +1 For pointing out that a custom `Iterator` could potentially instantiate new objects.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a new object is instantiated, its parent constructor is called before its own constructor (and so on up to `Object`). Since `StockRecord` extends `Stock`, when you call `new StockRecord` a certain `Stock` constructor is called before the specified `StockRecord` constructor. That's why you're seeing those print statements and in that order.

Answer (score 1):

The instances of `Stock` you're referencing in `s` at each iteration already exist. You are however creating a new instance of `StockRecord` every time (which may in turn create other instances of other classes).

Answer (score 0):

`Stock s` picks up reference from collection/array object `stock`. It will not create any object.

Comment: If `Stock` is super class of `StockRecord`. For that it could print.